# Django-Get Current User In Save Time

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How Can I Get Current User When I Want Save Something In Django Admin. I Mean When Overriding Save Method???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you mean? Do you always want to get current user when you override the Model.save() method, or when you save in Admin?

If you override the `ModelAdmin.save_model(...)` method you have access to the request, and thus the `request.user`, which is current user.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model